# CMD, REXX, need a way to detect an error

Tags: command, signals, rexx

I'm very very new to programming/coding.
And I have a very specific question, which I didn't find any answers to.
This command below executes perfectly fine if the command is valid.
If I enter an invalid command, an error occurs and the cmd exits.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVr8d.png)

But how do I make it, if an error happens, the program starts from the beginning rather than the cmd window closes?

So, in short, I want "SIGNAL start" to happen if an error occurs.

I hope you understand, thank you very much.

```
other:
    SAY "Enter your own command:"
    PULL command
    command

        IF command=ERROR THEN DO
        SIGNAL start
```

Comment: Have you tried `SIGNAL ON FAILURE start`?. You'd set this before attempting the command, probably followed by `SIGNAL OFF FAILURE` unless `start` handled all errors.

Comment: By followed, I mean after you issue the command.

Comment: You may find this of interest [The SIGNAL ON Condition](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSB27U_6.2.0/com.ibm.zvm.v620.dmsb0/sigoncd.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful if you published all of your code but it seems that what you really need to do is code a loop.

```
/* REXX */

do forever
  say "Enter a command"
  pull command
  "where" word(command,1)
  if rc <> 0 then iterate
  command
end
```